# Реверс слова с помощью регулярки

Tags: javascript, строки

На вход поступает слово переменной длины. Как средствами лишь регулярного выражения выдать перевёрнутое слово? Например, на входе `-йылеб` — нужно первернуть на `-белый`. Или `акчот` — `точка`. Ранее встречалось решение только с match в одном буржуйском блоге, но сейчас к нему доступа нет.

Comment: Тире до слова специально вставлено? Имею ввиду, что надо переворачивать именно буквы игнорируя знаки или тире просто выставлено и надо переворачивать любую строчку?

Comment: И какие методы строки можно использовать? Потому что с помощью обычного `str.split('').reverse().join('')`, можно спокойно перевернуть любую строчку

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать калбэк в replace для аккумулирования символов в обратном порядке. Например, так:

```
let s = '1234', rs = ''
s.replace(/[а-яА-Я\w]/g, m => rs = m + rs)
console.log(rs) // '4321'
```

Comment: Попробуйте строку `точка`. (Разве не было сказано, что `точка` нужно превратить в `акчот`?)

Comment: вы можете вместо "1234" использовать любое слово, и оно будет реверснуто. И да, если вы используете исходное слово "точка", оно будет реверснуто в "ачкот". У меня даже мысли не возникло, что это может быть не неочевидно)

Comment: не работает. Попробуйте "точка"  всё же подставить

Comment: @Александр А вы попробуйте любое русское слово)), у вас `\w` находит только английские :v

Comment: Поправил, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Если приемлимы варианты без регулярок, то предложу [самый быстрый способ](https://jsben.ch/uOJyl) сделать это:

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  let x = '';
  
  for (let i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      x += str[i];
  }
  
  return x;
}

console.log([
  'abcde',
  'qwerty',
  '12345',
  'абвгде'
].map(str => reverseString(str)));
```

Answer (score 0):

С тем же успехом развернуть можно и так...

```js
let s = '1234'
s = [...s].reduce((s, v) => v + s)
console.log(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

С тем же успехом развернуть можно и так...

```js
let s = '1234';
s = [...s].reverse().join``;
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну давай тогда и я уж свой способ предложу :)

```js
let str = '1234'
str = Object.values(str).reverse().join('')
console.log(str)
```

#### Объявление

Превращаем строку в массив, "переворачиваем" массив, и соединяем всё в одну строку.